# how to add number of days to date's output?

Tags: date

I'd like something like:

```
$ date --date="05/02/2012" "+2 days"
```

would give me "4 may" as output.. how ?

Comment: Did you try this command? {date -d "+2 days"}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming GNU date, you have almost the right command in your question:

```
$ date --date="05/02/2012 +2 days"
Fri May  4 00:00:00 EEST 2012
```

To get the exact string `4 May`, use this:

```
$ date --date="05/02/2012 +2 days" +"%e %b"
4 May
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem:

```
date --date="05/02/2012 2 day"
```

You can use `-` to compute days before:

```
date --date="05/02/2012 -2 day"
```